# Questions about the Internal of FormTools

Tags: python, django

To use [FormPreview](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/master/formtools/preview.py) I should subclass it and use it as View(?). But `FormPreview` is not a view. How does this works?

FormPreview has a lot of methods. Where are they called? For example `post_post`. It is never called in the FormPreview Class it is not called in not called by django. Or at least my `grep -inRI post_post` did not find its usage. How does that work?

If I set some attribute like `self.number = 42` in process_preview (subclassed and overridden method), then I can access this in the `done`-method. So I guess I am working on the same object. But I don't know how the Object life cycle works. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can be any callable - and doesn't need to be a class at all, as in function-based views. In this case, the callable object is an instance of the FormPreview class: it is callable because the class defines a `__call__` method.

The `post_post` method - along with other methods like `preview_get` - is called in [line 30](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/master/formtools/preview.py#L30), which dynamically looks up which method to call based on the stage and the request method.